# suspend fun is not waiting until await() in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have `suspend fun` to do the work in order.

```
suspend fun graphStepFun() {
        val startDate = LocalDate.of(
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )
        val endDate = LocalDate.of(
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )


        for (stepDate in startDate..endDate) {
            db.collection("user_step_count")
                .document("$userId")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { userSteps ->
                    userSteps.data?.forEach { (period, dateStepCount) ->
                        if (period == stepDate.toString()) {
                            thisWeekMyStepCount += (dateStepCount as Long).toInt()
                            Log.d("확인 1", "${thisWeekMyStepCount}")

                        }
                    }
                }.await()
        }
        Log.d("확인 2", "${thisWeekMyStepCount}")

        var daysDiffTime = thisWeekEnd.time - thisWeekStart.time
        var daysDiffDate = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(daysDiffTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        thisWeekMyStepCountAvg = ((thisWeekMyStepCount / (daysDiffDate+1).toDouble())).toInt()
        thisWeekMyStepPoint = (Math.round(thisWeekMyStepCountAvg / 1000.0)).toFloat()
    }
```

But when I print the `Log`.

확인2 (=result2) is printed before the last 확인1 (=result1) is ran.

```
 2023-02-26 20:58:47.478 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 15
    2023-02-26 20:58:47.678 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 646
    2023-02-26 20:58:47.812 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 740
    2023-02-26 20:58:47.916 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 740
    2023-02-26 20:58:48.031 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 753
    2023-02-26 20:58:48.116 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 765
    2023-02-26 20:58:48.256 2951-3063/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 2: 765
    2023-02-26 20:58:48.264 2951-2951/com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android D/확인 1: 2778
```

why it doesn't wait until completed result1?

So I also changed the code, each part to have separate fun:
`graphStepFun`, `graphStepCalculateFun`

```
suspend fun graphStepFun() {
        val startDate = LocalDate.of(
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekStart.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )
        val endDate = LocalDate.of(
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(0, 4).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(5, 7).toInt(),
            formatThisWeekEnd.substring(8, 10).toInt()
        )


        for (stepDate in startDate..endDate) {
            db.collection("user_step_count")
                .document("$userId")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { userSteps ->
                    userSteps.data?.forEach { (period, dateStepCount) ->
                        if (period == stepDate.toString()) {
                            thisWeekMyStepCount += (dateStepCount as Long).toInt()
                            Log.d("확인 1", "${thisWeekMyStepCount}")

                        }
                    }
                }.await()
        }
    }


suspend fun graphStepCalculateFun() {
        var daysDiffTime = thisWeekEnd.time - thisWeekStart.time
        var daysDiffDate = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(daysDiffTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        thisWeekMyStepCountAvg = ((thisWeekMyStepCount / (daysDiffDate+1).toDouble())).toInt()
        thisWeekMyStepPoint = (Math.round(thisWeekMyStepCountAvg / 1000.0)).toFloat()
    }
```

And run them in Coroutine scope.

```
  uiScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                listOf(
                    launch { graphStepFun() },
                    launch { graphDiaryFun() }
                ).joinAll()
                launch { graphStepCalculateFun() }.join()
                launch { dataToGraph() }.join()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    launch {
                        binding.rankingBarChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.rankingBarChartProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }
```

So graphStepFun is ran by `joinAll()` and graphStepCalculateFun() should run in my thought.

But result is also same, graphStepCalculateFun starts before graphStepFun is finished.

What is the problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem could be related to the fact you use `addOnSuccessListener()` and `await()` at the same time. Could you try to entirely remove `addOnSuccessListener()` and simply use a return value from `await()`?

Comment: Yes, I think there's a race condition, or at least undefined order from you using a listener and await() at the same time. There's no reason to use `addOnSuccessListener` if you're in a coroutine.